# MySQL SUM from Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: 'sending_fresh' and 'agents'

I would like to get the total where 'cc' equals a certain date from 'sending_fresh' and a specific team from 'agents'.

I currently have:

```
SELECT SUM(sending_fresh.cc), agents.team  
FROM sending_fresh, agents 
WHERE agents.team = 'team1' 
AND sending_fresh.date = '2012-05-12'
```

The sum works fine when selecting from just the 'sending_fresh' table but comes with a much higher and wrong answer when adding a WHERE statement from a second table.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the `GROUP BY` clause in your SQL? You're doing summation on `agents.team` and it obviously requires a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: what is the relationship between the two tables, is there a foreign key?

Comment: as @Arkain said, don't you need a `on col1=col2` ?

Comment: Umm I didn't think I would need it although my SQL skills are basic at best. Would that make the SUM work properly?

Comment: Yes, you need a join condition.  When you have two tables, you need a join (except in very peculiar circumstances).  In fact, when you have N tables (for N >= 1), you need N-1 joins.

Comment: yes the foreign key in 'sending_fresh' is 'agent_id' which corresponds to 'id' in the 'agents' table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main answer

> The foreign key in `sending_fresh` is `agent_id` which corresponds to `id` in the `agents` table.

You're missing a JOIN condition and you are missing a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT SUM(s.cc), a.team  
  FROM sending_fresh AS s
  JOIN agents        AS a ON a.id = s.agent_id
 WHERE a.team = 'team1' 
   AND s.date = '2012-05-12'
 GROUP BY a.team;
```

---

Before we had the information on the join, I wrote:

```
SELECT SUM(s.cc), a.team  
  FROM sending_fresh AS s
  JOIN agents        AS a ON a.team = s.team    -- Guess at join columns!
 WHERE a.team = 'team1' 
   AND s.date = '2012-05-12'
 GROUP BY a.team;
```

Since you missed out the join condition, I'm having to guess what it is.  It might instead be `a.team_id = s.team_id` or something like that instead.

<s>If the join is on `sending_fresh.team`, you could avoid the join altogether if you wish.</s>

```
SELECT SUM(cc), team  
  FROM sending_fresh
 WHERE team = 'team1' 
   AND date = '2012-05-12'
 GROUP BY team;
```

This simplification is not valid now the schema is known in more detail.

---

#### General comments

Note that using an explicit JOIN means you should not forget the join condition.  You should not use the comma-list of tables notation in the FROM clause.  You need to understand it to recognize antique SQL.  You should never use it in new SQL and you should upgrade old SQL to use explicit joins instead.

Note that if you have N tables in a query, you should have N-1 join conditions.